# How can I import data from a table in MS ACCESS 2007 to another table ?

Tags: ms-access

How can I import data from a table in MS ACCESS to another table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two tables are the same then this should do the trick

```
INSERT INTO tblSecond_table (your,columns,go,here)
SELECT (your,columns,go,here)
FROM tblFirst_table
```